# Java Find File inside of .jar with getResource()

Tags: java, file, jar, embedded-resource

I'm trying to get the `hibernate.cfg.xml` config file inside of an .jar file. The problem is that this throws an error when executed inside the .jar, but still works in Eclipse.

This is the entire error message I'm getting:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: jar:file:\C:\Projekte\middleware\de.ifd.middleware-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\target\middleware-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes!\hibernate.cfg.xml (Die Syntax f³r den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datentrõgerbezeichnung ist falsch)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(TransformerImpl.java:513)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:328)
        at middleware.HibernateUtil.init_Hibernate(HibernateUtil.java:111)
        at middleware.Main.main(Main.java:152)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:467)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: jar:file:\C:\Projekte\middleware\de.ifd.middleware-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\target\middleware-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes!\hibernate.cfg.xml (Die Syntax f³r den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datentrõgerbezeichnung ist falsch)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(TransformerImpl.java:498)
        ... 11 more
---------
java.io.FileNotFoundException: jar:file:\C:\Projekte\middleware\de.ifd.middleware-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\target\middleware-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes!\hibernate.cfg.xml (Die Syntax f³r den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datentrõgerbezeichnung ist falsch)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(TransformerImpl.java:498)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:328)
        at middleware.HibernateUtil.init_Hibernate(HibernateUtil.java:111)
        at middleware.Main.main(Main.java:152)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:467)
```

This is the code that probably throws the error:

```
public static void init_Hibernate() throws XPathExpressionException, SAXException, IOException,
            ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException {
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
            .parse(new InputSource(HibernateUtil.class.getResource("/hibernate.cfg.xml").toExternalForm()));

    // Not related stuff here
    
    System.out.println(HibernateUtil.class.getResource("/hibernate.cfg.xml").toExternalForm());
    Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    xformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc),
            new StreamResult(HibernateUtil.class.getResource("/hibernate.cfg.xml").toExternalForm()));
}
```

The sysout Statement prints the following:
`jar:file:/C:/Projekte/middleware/de.ifd.middleware-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/target/middleware-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/hibernate.cfg.xml`

The path seems to be correct, but I don't know why there are `!` behind .jar and classes.

I'm guessing there is something wrong with how I'm trying to get the file and I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: The second parameter of `transform` is the destination of the document. What are you trying to do? You can't update a file in a jar like that.

Comment: BTW - A Jar does not contain files, but resources. They must be accessed by URL and as noted by @tgdavies, they are not editable.

Comment: Thank you guys. I didn't knew you couldn't edit files inside a .jar file and this was the problem.

Comment: Generally, when you already have a `URL` and a class (also) accepting an `OutputStream`, it makes more sense to call `openConnection() .getOutputStream()` instead of converting the URL to a string and hoping that the `String` accepting constructor will do the right thing with that string. But as said by others, updating the resources of the currently running application is unlikely to work.